# K-fold cross validation with condition

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation

I have a classifier that takes a person's image as input.

I test the accuracy of this classifier using 10-fold cross-validation like so:

```
cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=10, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)
scores = cross_val_score(clf, features, tags, cv=cv)
```

However, I'd like the shuffle/split to not be so random,  and to take a certain condition into account.

For example's, let's say I have a data set with 10,000 images, but with only 10 different people.

So I would like the condition of the shuffle/split to be the person's ID- divide the data so that 1 person's images are either on the training set or the test set- not both.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Yes. See, [GroupShuffleSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupShuffleSplit.html)

Comment: @VivekKumar Perfect! thank you so much!